# Doctrine: How to mark object column value as dirty?

Tags: php, doctrine

I have a column of type [object](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#columns:data-types:object) in a model. But if I load a model, and change a property of the object, and then re-save, it doesn't seem re-serialize the object. e.g.

```
$model_instance = $table->find(1);
$object = $model_instance->object_column;
$object->someProp = 'new value';
$model_instance->save(); //has no effect
```

I think this is because it is checking for modification by comparing the old and new values using `!==`, which returns false because they are both references to the same object.

I could clone the object before saving but there clearly must be a more obvious way which I have missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

State is not changed because you don't update the field (just the reference). If you're interested how it happens read *set()* and *_set()* methods in *Doctrine_Record* class.

You can manually change the state of a record with a *state()* method:

```
$model_instance->state(Doctrine_Record::STATE_DIRTY);
```

This should force *save()* to persist your changes.